# Detect Data Annotation Validation on the View without javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Is there a way I can detect if validation summary information is being posted without Javascript. I am using Data Annotations in my model in Asp.Net MVC. It does successfully return to the page any data errors like required fields. But I see those data errors are not visible in my model that is being returned to my view. Is there a way I can detect if there are errors in my view without javascript?

Comment: Are you including the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` and/or `@Html.ValidationSummary()` helper methods in the view?

Comment: Both those are in my View. They work perfectly. What I want to do though is detect if there is validation errors on the view without JavaScript. That way I can decide to or not to hide a div.